# Is there a way to disable code autocomplete in the Python window in ArcGIS 10.0

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python

Autocomplete slows down my workflow in the Python window, especially if I am remoted into a machine.

Is there a way to disable this?

Alternatively, a way to disable this and then invoke as needed (similar to Intellisense options in Visual Studio)?

Answer (score 7):

I use Pythonwin as my Python IDE.  In that environment, and I am sure in others, you can simply toggle it off.  For Pythonwin, try the menu option View | Editor, then toggle off autocomplete.

EDIT  I should add you are under no obligation to use the one provided in ArcMap, simply fire up your favourite IDE and >>> import arcpy    which will give you full access to the arcpy module.  If you have frequently used expressions, particularly complex ones associated with the spatial analyst module, use a text editor to save them, then cut/paste and modify to suit.

ESRI dev types are also touting [pyscripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/) as a pretty full-fledge, open source Python interpreter...I would keep an eye open to see if this gets bundled at some stage as a replacement for Pythonwin.  It has more capabilities and it rivals (apparently) some commercial Python IDEs
[1](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/)

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: no, there is no way to disable it.

Answer (score 2):

Tools>Options>IDE Options: Uncheck complete as you type. I don't know if there is a way to toggle it with hot keys. That is what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: In ArcMap 10.0 there is no Tools menu. What program do you access this setting?

Answer (score 0):

in pyscripter you can do the same and then ctrl+spacebar to bring it back as needed

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

Click tools>preferences>editor>code introspection.

Go there and uncheck auto complete

Comment: I could not find this option in ArcGIS 10.4 - are you seeing it in 10.0 only or in something earlier/later?

Comment: I also cannot find this option in ArcGIS 10.2. Where exactly do you find it? Could you post a screenshot?

Answer (score -1):

switch off hint, that shown in image, It will work properly.  open jupyter notebook , go to option " HELP" / continuous hints [image]